# Setting constraints for parameters in pytorch

Tags: python, vector, pytorch

I am trying to set some constraints for weight parameters in PyTorch, e.g. the sum of every row of the weight matrix be exactly one for a fully connected layer:

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.layer1 = nn.Linear(28*28, 10*10)
        self.layer2 = nn.Linear(10*10, 5*5)
        self.layer3 = nn.Linear(5*5, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x=torch.sigmoid(self.layer1(x))
        x=torch.sigmoid(self.layer2(x))
        x=torch.sigmoid(self.layer3(x))

model=Net()
```

The constraint for this example network would be:

```
torch.sum(model.linear1.weight,0)==1
torch.sum(model.linear2.weight,0)==1
torch.sum(model.linear3.weight,0)==1
```

A commonly used method to set a constraint, `clamp`, is used to set constraints for every element, but in this case, I would be setting a constraint for every row, instead of any particular element of the weight matrix. Are there any ways to implement this kind of constraint?

Comment: Please define your question better in terms of inputs and required outputs. As it is now, it is not answerable.

Comment: Also "`clamp` is not helpful" is not a helpful statement

Comment: why do you want this constraint for weights in the first place? Is it a experiment?

Comment: @Gulzar Thanks, added some code example to clarify

Comment: @RNanthak Some more complex constraints are required for the experiment, but I stumble for even the most simple cases, sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way I can think about is for example to normalize the vector of your choosing by its norm, which will give its direction, with size 1.

```
w0 = model.linear1.weight[0, :]
w0_hat = w0 / torch.linalg.norm(w0) # direction of w0, norm=1
```

I don't really see a way of doing this for the `.sum`, but I also don't see why one would want to.

---

Using L1 norm would do that for the `.sum` if you can guarantee the weights are all non-negative. Probably this isn't what you want.

---

If you insist of normalizing such that the `.sum` will equal to 1, you have to define the normalization yourself, because there is no single algorithm to decide which weight index gets changed, and by how much.

Comment: The first implementation is fine! The `.sum` was just for clarification purposes and is indeed unnecessary.